# why mysql doesn‘t lock a row in repeatable read mode when two transaction are updating at the same time?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, scala, transactions

I don't know if I forgot to set some property to enable this.
I have two transactions that will change the same row in the same table.

```
  val f1 = Future {
  mysqlDB.withTransaction {
    implicit session =>
      println("one===========query begin")
      val name = Tables.User.filter(_.id === 2).map(_.name).run
      println("one=========="+name)
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      println("one update change to x-f1")
      Tables.User.filter(_.id === 2).map(_.name).update(name + "-f1")
      println(Tables.User.filter(_.id === 2).run)
      println("one============query end")
  }
}

val f2 = Future {
  mysqlDB.withTransaction {
    implicit session =>
      println("two===========query begin")
      val name = Tables.User.filter(_.id === 2).map(_.name).run
      println("two==========="+name)
      Thread.sleep(2800)
      println("two update change to x-f2")
      Tables.User.filter(_.id === 2).map(_.name).update(name + "-f2")
      println(Tables.User.filter(_.id === 2).run)
      println("two============query end")
  }
}

Await.result(f1, 10.seconds)
Await.result(f2, 10.seconds)
```

I test postgresql and mysql using the same code above(they are all in repeatable mode).I think the "one" transaction will fail because the concurrency update.

In fact,postgresql does,but mysql runs without exception and the "one" transaction overwrote the result of the "two" transaction.It means the result is lost that is very annoying.

```
    Run starting. Expected test count is: 2
    JDBCTestSpec2:
    transcation
    two===========query begin
    one===========query begin
    one============Vector(ccc)
    two==========Vector(ccc)
    two update change to x-f2
    Vector(UserRow(2,Vector(ccc)-f2))
    two============query end
    one update change to x-f1
    - should lock a row(postgresql) *** FAILED ***
      org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 错误: 由于同步更新而无法串行访问
      at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
      at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
      at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
      at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:560)
      at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
      at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
      at scala.slick.driver.JdbcInvokerComponent$UpdateInvoker$$anonfun$update$1.apply(JdbcInvokerComponent.scala:88)
      at scala.slick.driver.JdbcInvokerComponent$UpdateInvoker$$anonfun$update$1.apply(JdbcInvokerComponent.scala:84)
      at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:191)
      at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:389)
      ...
    transcation
    two===========query begin
    one===========query begin
    two===========Vector(ccc)
    one==========Vector(ccc)
    two update change to x-f2
    Vector(UserRow(2,Vector(ccc)-f2))
    two============query end
    one update change to x-f1
    Vector(UserRow(2,Vector(ccc)-f1))
    one============query end
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

The problem is solved.And I have posted some code to github using `FOR UPDATE`:
https://gist.github.com/fairjm/99ce55160d4a4adf350b

Comment: This question is unrelated to Java.

Comment: Are you sure you are using two different (physical) connections and thus two _different_ transactions?

Comment: I don't know much about postgres, but  in mysql(innodb), by default, the `plain SELECT`(without explicit lock, eg for update) will lock nothing, it just ensure all select statements are consistent with each other here. You could perform a compare then update sql like `set name = "new" where name = "old"` .  Take a look at here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read

Comment: And make sure only `innodb` support transaction.

Comment: @jilen I have checked that the table in mysql is using innodb(and it's the default engine in mysql 5.7)

Comment: @jilen set name="new" where name="old" is a good idea.Thank you so much,^_^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed @jilen table must use InnoDB storage engine to support transactions in MySQL.
To convert a table to be an InnoDB table run statement:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

*Note:*

If you need lock selected record you must use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` ([mysql syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html); [postgresql syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)). It [is not supported natively in Slick](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/92) but there is a workaround: https://gist.github.com/cvogt/d9049c63fc395654c4b4

*References:*

1. [Transaction and Atomic Operation Differences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)
2. [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)
3. [Feature Request: Support for "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE"](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/92)

Comment: yes,after I apply `val query = Tables.User.filter(_.id === 2).map(_.name);
          Q.queryNA[String](query.selectStatement + " FOR UPDATE").execute`.The result in mysql becomes `-f2-f1` that `f2` is not lost now.But I think it's still strange and the result of postgresql is what I want.Whatever,thx so much.^_^

Comment: @fairjm: If "the result of postgresql" is what you want, the sure method is to *actually use* Postgres. There are many subtle differences in handling of concurrency, and MySQL is a (relatively) inexperienced newcomer in this area.

Comment: I agree with @ErwinBrandstetter. To get similar, but not exact, effect in MySQL you can use [SERIALIZABLE isolation level (same as REPEATABLE READ with added share mode locks on SELECT statements)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable). But it has a side effect: first update will wait until second fails.